# How to calculate a polynomial function with a few given equations

Tags: functions

How can I calculate a polynomial function for which the following (or other) mappings / equations are true?

$f(0) = 0$

$f(10000) = 0$

$f(100000) = 10$

$f(1000000) = 30$

$f(100000000) = 90$

(I completely forgot how to do this to be honest.)

Comment: This should help you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: A polynomial will not give nice values for numbers over several orders of magnitude.  If $\log$s are possible, you might try a polynomial in $\log x$, so try $p(x)=a(\log x)^4+b(\log x)^3+c(\log x)^2+d\log x+e$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find a polynomial passing through given points, take the polynomial $p(x) = ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$, substitute the values of $x$ and $p(x)$, and solve a linear system. The linear system must have a solution (this is the case in your example).

However, if you want a minimum-degree polynomial passing through a set of given points, you can use polynomial interpolation methods.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to solve the linear system.. This is probably very basic algebra, but what are my next steps for this: $a*100000^4 - a*10*10000^4 = 10$ /// What would I do if I want the function to return 90 for a any value equal or above 100000000? (a sort of maximum value) Is this also possible with what you described?

Comment: No. It is not possible to do this with this method. Actually, there is no finite polynomial that satisfies $p(x) = 90$ for $x \geq 10^8$. You must use a finite number of points and an  interpolation method for fitting your data.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Can you help me regarding my other question? (the beginning of my first comment)

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/FtibKhb2) is what my equations must look like, right?

Comment: Ok. But what is exactly your question? Do you ask for the next step for $100000^4a - 10\cdot 10000^4 a = 10$? What is the matter?

Comment: Okay that has been settled. I just had a problem solving it for $a$. Thanks!